# Django recive array ajax problem

Tags: python, ajax, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm sending array via POST reqest to Django server 
if I use dev server, I see

```
 <QueryDict: {u'arr[]': [u'1', u'2']}>
```

if I send to Apache+Mod_wsgi sever, I see

```
 <QueryDict: {u'arr[]': [u'2']}>
```

olny last item, any ideas?

upd: dev sever on my local pc, if Apache+mod_wsgi on my local pc all fine, if on remote - only last item

Comment: Are you positive you formatted your code in the question correctly? Is the `</pre>` tag really there in your data dump?

Comment: what does request.GET.getlist('arr') return?

Comment: is server located on my local pc ['1','2'], on remote ['2']. request.POST in "on remote case" doesn't contains ['1']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:
serialize array with [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

```
JSON.stringify(my_array)
```

and deserialize with

```
import json
json.loads(str)
```